# Como estruturar as anotações relacionamento de Entity do hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, relacionamento, annotation

Gostaria de entender a diferença entre as anotações do hibernate com o JPA: @OneToOne, @OneToMany, @ManyToMany e @ManyToOne do hibernate, como funciona?

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com Hibernate mas essas anotações se referem ao tipo de entidade-relacionamento numa modelagem de banco de dados. Por exemplo, uma classe Post possui como atributos autor, id, conteúdo e uma lista de comentários. Comentários possui a anotação @OneToMany, ou seja, UM post pode ter vários comentários.

Comment: Você quer um tutorial sobre anotações JPA? Se você tiver uma dúvida mais específica, atualize a pergunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**@One-To-One:** A associação de One-to-One é semelhante à associação many-to-one com a diferença de que a coluna será definido como único.
Exemplo:

```
@OneToOne 
public Endereco getEndereco() { 
     return this.endereco; 
}
```

**Many-to-One:** A associação de many-to-one é o tipo mais comum de associação em que um objeto pode ser associado a vários objetos. Exemplo:

```
@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "publicador_id") 
public Publicador getPublicador() {
    return publicador; 
}
```

**One-to-Many:** A anotação @OneToMany pode ser aplicada para um campo ou propriedade de uma coleção ou um array representando o "many" da associação.
Exemplo:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "publicador") 
public Set<Livro> getLivros() { 
     return livros; 
}
```

**Many-ToMany:** Exemplo:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = ALL) 
public Set<Autor> getAutores() { 
     return autores; 
}
```

Links onde retirei as informações:

[devmedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/hibernate-mapping-mapeando-relacionamentos-entre-entidades/29445)

[tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_many_to_one_mapping.htm)