# banco de dados java spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, maven

Boa noite, estou com uma dúvida em meus estudos, estou fazendo um projeto para treinar conhecimento e me deparei com um problema.

Tenho uma classe User:

```
@Entity 
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String password;

@OneToMany
private List<Service> services = new ArrayList<>();
//get and set
```

E uma Service:

```
@Entity
public class Service {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String description;
private String userService;
private String password;
```

Minha dúvida é, como buscar a List dos serviços de um usuário?

Ao meu ver terei que criar um atributo em serviços e nele setar o id de um usuário? Mas desse jeito num ficaria um banco "pesado"? onde terei que percorrer todos o banco procurando pelo serviço que tem aquele "USER_ID"

Answer (score 1):

> Minha dúvida é, como buscar a List dos serviços de um usuário?

Apenas: `user.getServices()`. Ao fazer essa chamada será retornado um `List<Service>`.

> Ao meu ver terei que criar um atributo em serviços e nele setar o id de um usuário?  (...) onde terei que percorrer todos o banco procurando pelo serviço que tem aquele "USER_ID"

Não é necessário, pois o Hibernate/JPA sabe como obter os dados na base de dados (por meio do método `find()`, por exemplo) a partir das anotações da classe de entidade.

Contudo, pode ser que apenas anotar o atributo `services` com `@OneToMany` na classe de entidade `User` não seja o suficiente para o Hibernate/JPA funcionar. Você pode aprender mais em questões já respondidas aqui no StackOverflow:

- [Mapeamentos JPA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76274/4761)
- [Mapeamentos unidirecionais vs bidirecionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/234768/4761)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas ao tentar usar o user.getServices() me é gerado exceções.

Answer (score 0):

ERRO ao usar user.getServices() :

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
... 48 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: rememberPassword.model.User.services, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:597)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:216)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:576)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:147)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.get(PersistentBag.java:477)
at rememberPassword.controller.MainScreenController.autentication(MainScreenController.java:94)
... 58 more
```

Método utilizado para ver a lista de servicos e que me gera o erro acima:

```
        Optional<User> usuario = userReposi.findById(1L);

    System.out.println("Descricao serv: " + usuario.get().getServices().get(0).getDescription());
```

Comment: Por gentileza edite sua pergunta e adicione estas informações nela, não como resposta. De qualquer forma, essa exceção ocorre devido à sessão do Hibernate já ter sido fechada. Por gentileza poste também o método e classe completa de onde você está chamando o Repository